# Creating an object through an object constructor in JS that is located in a separate js file

Tags: javascript, file, object, constructor, external

My problem in **short**: I've created an object constructor in a js file (file name: generation.js) and I would like to create an object with that constructor in an other js file (file name: timeline.js). When I try to do this, I get the error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: generation *(the object I want to create)* is not defined.

In the HTML I have the js files in proper order: first the generation.js, then timeline.js. I also have the jQuery line in place.
If I try to use the constructor in the same file where the object definition is (in generation.js), it works properly. Then I copy + past that code to the new file and it doesn't work anymore.

**The code:**

**Generation.JS:**

*This is where I defined the object constructor*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function  generation() {
    this.var1 = '';
    ....  // some variables
    this.genFactory = function(agents) { // some function that creates even more
    objects and other functions
    };
};
});
```

**Timeline.JS:**

*This is where I would like to create an instance of the generation object*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#start').click(function(){
          console.log('ASD'); //just to check if the file works
          gen1 = new generation(); //the error message points here
          gen1.genFactory(3);
          gen1.shuffle(individuals); //this is just an other method of the
          generation object

   });
});
```

Just to make sure that Timeline.js works: The console logs 'ASD'.

Looking forward for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should expose your `generation` function to the public by assigning it to the window. A general approach in such cases is to have an `app` variable which contains all such object constructors and variables. In your Generation.js file you should use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.app = window.app || {};

    app.generation = function () {
        this.var1 = '';
        ....  // some variables
        this.genFactory = function(agents) { // some function that creates even more
        objects and other functions
        };
    };
});
```

And in your Timeline.js file you will call your constructor as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.app = window.app || {};

   $('#start').click(function(){
          console.log('ASD'); //just to check if the file works
          gen1 = new app.generation(); //the error message points here
          gen1.genFactory(3);
          gen1.shuffle(individuals); //this is just an other method of the
          generation object

   });
})
```

Comment: Unless you explicitly assign `window.app` somewhere, both closures will end up assigning to their own local `var`s.

Comment: Yep, sorry for that, fixed it :)

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Could you please explain what this piece of code does exactly? I guess it creates an app object that inherits from window. And why do I have to include that line in both files?

Comment: It attaches an object to the window, does not create a one inherriting from it. You have to include that line in both files in case the one loads before the other. This way you will work with the same instance of object in both files.